Looking for ClangFormat assistant tools in customization of .clang-format options
I'm in the process of standing up a simple formatting pipeline, probably destined for ADO, for a particular product codebase, natural focus on rounding out as much as we can with ClangFormat. The codebase itself has a particularly idiosyncratic style, and very little in the way of anything formally documented for preferences, causing some pain in the process of trying to represent our preferred style in terms of CF options, of which there are an absolute mountain.
I'm hoping to find some kind of assistant tool for this process, and envisioning a sort of visualizer that could work with sample source files to determine which rules best apply, or maybe one that could build up from scratch. My mind's eye is giving me something like Godbolt for CF (I see GB supports CF as well, but seemingly no support for easily passing a CF config file).
Any idea if such tools exist? Principle languages of relevance are C/++, with a natural preference for FOSS.
Thanks.
